# Dynamically inserted primefaces componenets not rendered properly

Tags: ajax, components, rendering, primefaces

Why aren't the Primefaces components rendered properly on partial page update?

The problem is -

I have a view with ui:include -

```
<ui:include src="#{navBean.viewId}.xhtml}"/>
```

and p:commandButton -

```
<p:commandButton action="#{navBean.setViewId('page1')}" value="Load DataTable"/>
```

and page1.xhtml is where I have a p:dataTable

```
<ui:composition xmlns ...
    <h:head/>
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable ...
```

Now, when I click on the command button, partial update takes place and everything is loaded but the data table is not rendered properly.

Does anybody here know how to get around this problem?

I went through some of the topics in the Primefaces forum but they didn't do any good.

Thank you.

Comment: Whoever down voted this question could at least left a hint about why he down voted or some or some clue on what's causing the problem, so that I could work on it.
Just down vote and take off, that's kind of rude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple -

Just include a

```
<h:head/>
```

as follows -

```
<ui:composition xmlns ...
    <h:head/>
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable ...
```

And now the p:dataTable renders as it is supposed to even on partial page update.